# How to transfer value from a callback function in pageA to pageB in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to transfter a value from callback function in PageA to a function in PageB. PageA is parent to PageB which is an iframe in PageA. Here is the scenarion

**PageA.js(js of Parent window)**

```js
const my_data = {
   from
};
$('#seekSlider').ionRangeSlider({
  //Callback
  onFinish: function(data) {

    my_data.from = data.from;
    onFinished();
  }
});

function onFinished(){
    return my_data;
}
```

**PageB.js(js of Child window opened in iframe)**

```js
let data = window.parent.onFinished();
console.log(data);
```

[ioRangeSlider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo_interactions.html) is a plugin for HTML range slider, and it has a callback function that i want to invoke in the iframe pageB.

The snippet above is what i have tried but there is not object passed from parent to child in the console. I would appreciate any idea.

Comment: "it does not work' is [not a useful description of the problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Describe what you expected to happen. Describe what actually happened. Describe the difference. Make sure you look at the Developer Tools in your browser. Check the Console for error messages. Add `console.log` statements to the JS to make sure that the your functions are running and that variables contain the values you expect. Break your code down to check things like `window.parent.$('#onFinishValue').length` to make sure that the elements you are searching for with jQuery exist.

Comment: You should also provide a [mcve]. Use the *live demo* feature in the question editor. I've no idea what `ionRangeSlider` is.

Comment: Basically what i want is to invoke a callback function(onFinish) defined in parent page from an iframe page. something like window.parent.onFinish()

Comment: I added more descriptions for the problem. I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i came up to fix my problem. In order for the parent window to communicate to the child window opened in iframe, i had to add some functionalities in the the callback function onFinish() like this

**PageA.js(js of Parent window)**

```js
$('#seekSlider').ionRangeSlider({

       //Callback
       onFinish: function(data) {

       const iframeEl = document.getElementById('my_frame');

       //..send the message object 'data' to the child window (iframe)
       iframeEl.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), '*');
   }
});
```

**PageB.js(js of Child window opened in iframe)**

```js
function bindEvent(element, eventName, eventHandler)
{
        if (element.addEventListener)
        {
            element.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false);
        }
        else if (element.attachEvent)
        {
            element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, eventHandler);
        }
 }

 //..listen to messages from parent window
 bindEvent(window, 'message', function (e) {

        const obj = JSON.parse(e.data);

        console.log(obj); 
  });
```